# Insert rows based on two or more conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, rows

Each row has an ID and a sequence of multiple types of lamps (type) and power (watts)

[image]

I need to pick values and insert them in the main sheet in an specific way according to the following conditions:

1. If in the same row there are 2 lamps that are equal in both power (watts) and type, then a string type+power should be inserted in the type column of another sheet.
2. If in the same row there are lamps with different powers (watts) or types, then the other type of lamp should be inserted below the first row with the same ID. For example:

[image]

Can you guys help me?

Comment: *I want to know if theres a way to make a VBA code* Yes, please post what you've tried, and where are you stuck

Comment: This macro is not easy. With the information you posted is not sufficient. How many columns of data can there be? .. To do this macro you need to compare all type of lamps and powers to each other. If there are let's say 5 type/watts columns then you need to compare 1 with 2, 1 with 3, .. until 5.. then 2 with 1, 2 with 3, 2 with 4... for each row. Then do it all over again with the second condition.

Comment: What are those numbers in columns E, H and K?

Comment: @Gassz The maximum amount of columns of data that can exist are 10 (for each watt and type) this numer before the lamp type and watts is quantity of lamps.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey The amount of lamps.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I don't know VBA very much. What I tryied to do was creating a code that would transpose the data to a vertical column automatically but I was not able to insert any criteria or any IF/ELSE function to the code.

Comment: So why are you counting only 1 SV400?

Comment: it would be useful if you could put a picture of the real data showing all the columns

Comment: @Gassz I can't do it unfortunately because the company don't allow me to share this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub SubTotals()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DblResultCounter As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    Dim RngStartingCell As Range
    Dim RngFirstData As Range
    Dim RngIDList As Range
    Dim RngID As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim StrResult() As String
    Dim StrWatts As String
    Dim StrType As String
    
    'Creating a new worksheet.
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngStartingCell = Range("A1")
    Set RngFirstData = Range("F2")
    StrWatts = "WATTS"
    StrType = "TYPE"
    
    'Setting RngIDList.
    Set RngIDList = Range(RngStartingCell.Offset(1, 0), RngStartingCell.End(xlDown))
    
    'Covering each cell in RngIDList.
    For Each RngID In RngIDList
        
        'Setting RngTarget as the last cell on the right with data.
        Set RngTarget = Cells(RngID.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        
        'Covering all the columns with data.
        Do Until RngTarget.Column <= RngFirstData.Column
            
            'Searching for the next columns with StrWatts and StrType as headers.
            Do Until Cells(RngStartingCell.Row, RngTarget.Column).Value = StrWatts And _
                     Cells(RngStartingCell.Row, RngTarget.Column - 1).Value = StrType
                Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(0, -1)
            Loop
            
            'Reporting the results.
            DblResultCounter = DblResultCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve StrResult(1 To 3, 1 To DblResultCounter)
            StrResult(1, DblResultCounter) = RngID.Value
            StrResult(2, DblResultCounter) = RngTarget.Offset(0, -1).Value & RngTarget.Value
            StrResult(3, DblResultCounter) = RngTarget.Offset(0, -2).Value
            
            Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(0, -1)
        Loop
    Next
    
    'Setting RngTarget as the last of the cell in RngIdList.
    Set RngTarget = RngIDList.Cells(RngIDList.Rows.Count, 1)
    
    'Covering the whole list from the bottom up.
    Do Until RngTarget.Row = RngStartingCell.Row
        
        'Covering each value in StrResult().
        For DblCounter01 = 1 To DblResultCounter
            
            'Checking if the IDs match.
            If RngTarget.Value = StrResult(1, DblCounter01) Then
                
                'Reporting the results.
                RngTarget.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
                RngTarget.Offset(1, 0).Value = StrResult(1, DblCounter01)
                RngTarget.Offset(1, 1).Value = StrResult(3, DblCounter01)
                RngTarget.Offset(1, 2).Value = StrResult(2, DblCounter01)
                
            End If
        Next
        
        Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(-1, 0)
    Loop
    
    'Sorting the list.
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=RngTarget.EntireColumn, _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=RngTarget.Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn, _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range(RngStartingCell, Cells(RngStartingCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).EntireColumn
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        .SortFields.Clear
    End With
    
    'Setting RngTarget as the last cell of the list.
    Set RngTarget = RngStartingCell.End(xlDown)
    
    'Covering the whole list from the bottom up.
    Do Until RngTarget.Address = RngStartingCell.Address
        
        'Checking if the actual row has the same item as the row above.
        If RngTarget.Offset(0, 0).Value = RngTarget.Offset(-1, 0).Value And _
           RngTarget.Offset(0, 2).Value = RngTarget.Offset(-1, 2).Value Then
            
            'Making one row of the two.
            RngTarget.Offset(0, 1).Value = RngTarget.Offset(0, 1).Value + RngTarget.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            RngTarget.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            
        Else
            Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(-1, 0)
        End If
        
    Loop
    
    'Setting RngTarget as the last cell of the list.
    Set RngTarget = RngStartingCell.End(xlDown)
    
    'Covering the whole list from the bottom up.
    Do Until RngTarget.Address = RngStartingCell.Address
        
        'Counting how many rows with the ID reported in RngTarget are in the list.
        DblCounter01 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(RngStartingCell, RngTarget), RngTarget.Value)
        
        'Checking if there is more than 1 row with the same ID.
        If DblCounter01 > 1 Then
            
            'Cut-pasting the source data.
            RngTarget.EntireRow.Resize(1, Columns.Count - 3).Offset(0, 3).Cut RngTarget.Offset(-DblCounter01 + 1, 3)
            Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(-DblCounter01, 0)
            RngTarget.Offset(DblCounter01, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            Set RngTarget = RngTarget.Offset(-DblCounter01, 0)
        End If
        
    Loop
    
    
End Sub
```

It creates a new sheet with the result you are looking for. If you don't want it to be in a new sheet but instead wants to edit the source sheet itself, just delete the line `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet`.

The task could most likely be accomplished with a shorter code. I choose a longer approach because i wanted to use a good share of basic commands; this way you might learn more basic stuff from it.

Comment: It really helped me. Thank you a lot! I will keep studying VBA and this will be really useful.

Comment: I have just one question. This code helped me a lot, but I was trying to edit it in order to make possible for me to add more columns besides the ID, QUANTITY AND LAMP, with informations that, just like the ID, would be duplicated. In other words, I was trying to find a way to create more columns with data, and this data would be duplicated just like the ID when it's necessary. What part of the code should I edit to make that possible?

Comment: I'd say anything concerning `StrResult()`. You might also need to shift the data to the right (therefore changing also the `RngFirstData` setting) if you want to preserve them at the side of your larger report. To be sure i'd need details. In such case it would be another question. You might try your edit and if you get stuck you might pose another question.

Comment: Hi, is there a way of write this code without sorting the worksheet? I tried to change that but everytime I do it nothing happens.

Comment: Usually when i need to maintain the order of a list that i need to sort temporarly, i create an extra column and fill it with increasing values. I then sort the whole thing and once i'm done i use the said column to restore the original order. Would that work for you?

Comment: I think yes, but how can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like a new question to me. I'll give you some tips: [Range.EntireColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirecolumn) [Range.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) [Range.Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.delete) [Range.Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) [For Each... Next statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement).

Comment: You should determine where in the code you should create the new column, insert it, define the new range as an offset of `RngIDList`, use a For Each... Next statement to fill it with numbers, adapt the sorting to include the new column, let the code sort and process it, re-sort it once it's done and delete the column. Try it and if you can't succeed you may post a new question with your new code.